# System monitoring tool via command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, resources

Is there a command line tool for Windows XP to display system resources, like available memory usage, cpu, diskspace etc... Small and requires a non-install.

Best Regards,

Anders

Comment: By "non-install" do you mean something portable, or something which will already be included in a normal installation of Windows XP?

Comment: I mean a single .exe file that can run out of the box on any standard Windows XP installation. Requiring no "installation process", but if there are internal available tools already in Windows, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMIC can be used to find pretty much anything you want provided you are prepared to do a bit of digging - for information similar to the examples you asked about:

```
wmic computersystem get DNSHostname, Domain, Manufacturer, Model, NumberofLogicalProcessors, NumberofProcessors, SystemType, TotalPhysicalMemory
wmic logicaldisk get Caption, FileSystem, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName
```

`SystemInfo` will give you a good overall summary but with WMIC you can tune the queries to give you just the data you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Use systeminfo:

```
    C:\>systeminfo

   Host Name: CONAN
   OS Name: Microsoft Windows XP Professional
   OS Version: 5.1.2600 Build 2600
   OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
   OS Configuration: Standalone Workstation
   OS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free
   Registered Owner: John Savill
   Registered Organization: SavillTech Ltd
   Product ID: 55274-005-0147286-22895
   Original Install Date: 30/11/2001, 09:49:41
   System Up Time: N/A
   System Manufacturer: Compaq
   System Model: Professional Workstation AP550
   System type: X86-based PC
   Processor(s): 2 Processor(s) Installed.
    [01]: x86 Family 6 Model 8 Stepping 6 GenuineIntel ~863 Mhz
    [02]: x86 Family 6 Model 8 Stepping 6 GenuineIntel ~863 Mhz
   BIOS Version: COMPAQ - 20010410
   Windows Directory: G:\WINDOWS
   System Directory: G:\WINDOWS\System32
   Boot Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
   System Locale: en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
   Input Locale: en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
   Time Zone: (GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon,
   London
   Total Physical Memory: 512 MB
   Available Physical Memory: 197 MB
   Virtual Memory: Max Size: 994 MB
   Virtual Memory: Available: 460 MB
   Virtual Memory: In Use: 534 MB
   Page File Location(s): N/A
   Domain: FMMS
   Logon Server: \\CONAN
   Hotfix(s): 16 Hotfix(s) Installed.
    [01]: File 1
    [02]: Q147222
    [03]: Q282784 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q282784 for more
   information]
    [04]: Q307869 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q307869 for more
   information]
    [05]: Q308210 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q308210 for more
   information]
    [06]: Q309521 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q309521 for more
   information]
    [07]: Q309691 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q309691 for more
   information]
    [08]: Q310437 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q310437 for more
   information]
    [09]: Q310507 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q310507 for more
   information]
    [10]: Q311889 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q311889 for more
   information]
    [11]: Q313484 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q313484 for more
   information]
    [12]: Q315000 - Windows XP Hotfix (SP1) [See Q315000 for more
   information]
    [13]: Q282784 - Update
    [14]: Q311889 - Update
    [15]: Q313484 - Update
    [16]: Q315000 - Update
   NetWork Card(s): 1 NIC(s) Installed.
    [01]: Intel(R) 82559 Fast Ethernet LOM with Alert on LAN*
   Connection Name: Local Area Connection
   DHCP Enabled: No
   IP address(es)
    [01]: 200.200.200.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you need more detailed informations, you can find the tools needed in the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx), take a look at Psinfo.exe -d and Pslist for example. You can also roll your own VBScript querying WMI information.